# Creating tables via loop from the levels of one variable

Tags: r, loops, datatables

I'm currently making tables in R and am wondering if there is a way to make my process a lot less tedious. I"m making tables with two variables, however I am going through the levels of the first variable and creating a table for each level based off the second variable. An example of the code is below:

`prop.table(table(df[df$v1 == 6 , c("v1" , "v2")]))*100`

Variable v1 has 6 levels, i would like to create a loop that would start from 1 up to 6 (all variables are numeric, however not all of them end at 6) and generate tables for each level of v1 to v2.

Variable v2 has two levels, not sure if that is relevant but just in case it is.

Thank you!

EDIT: I've included sample code and desired output tables, apologies for not including these before!

EDIT2: Updated the tables to correctly show the expected outputs. My apologies for all the mistakes while posting this question, next questions will be much better formatted. Thank you everyone for your help!

```r
id <- 1:20
age <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
gender <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2)
response <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(id, age, gender, response)
```

Here is an example of the table outputs I would like to see from the loop generated. It iterates through each level of the `age` variable (6 levels) with the `response` variable. I'd like this loop to apply to the `gender` variable as well, which has 5 levels.

| age | response (0) | response (1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 67% | 33% |

| age | response (0) | response (1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 50% | 50% |

| age | response (0) | response (1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 100% | 0% |

| age | response (0) | response (1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 50% | 50% |

| age | response (0) | response (1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 50% | 50% |

| age | response (0) | response (1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 50% | 50% |

Comment: If you’re working in the tidyverse, `group_map` (or similar) will be your friend. As @MrFlick has said, a reproducible example will be helpful - and make it more likely others will help you.

Comment: Edited, very sorry for not including this before!

Comment: I think you are looking for something wrangeld from `aggregate(response ~ age, data = df, \(x) table(x) / length(x) * 100)`, but it is hard to tell. I suspect your expected output is not in accordance to your toy data.

Comment: I don't understand something. In your example data, there are 6 observations with age == 1, 4 of which have response 0 and 2 of which have response 1. How does that map your 40%/60% for 0/1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  count(age, response) |>
  complete(age, response, fill = list(n=0)) |>
  mutate(share = n / sum(n), .by = age)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
     age response     n share
   <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1     1        0     4 0.667
 2     1        1     2 0.333
 3     2        0     2 0.5  
 4     2        1     2 0.5  
 5     3        0     0 0    
 6     3        1     2 1    
 7     4        0     2 0.5  
 8     4        1     2 0.5  
 9     5        0     1 0.5  
10     5        1     1 0.5  
11     6        0     1 0.5  
12     6        1     1 0.5
```

Comment: When I run this code I get different values in the share column, for example I get 0.2 and 0.1 for age 1 (response 0) and age 1 (response 1) respectively. Some output:

# A tibble: 12 × 5
     age response     n share   .by
   <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1        0     4  0.2      1
 2     1        1     2  0.1      1
 3     2        0     2  0.1      2
 4     2        1     2  0.1      2
 5     3        0     0  0        3
 6     3        1     2  0.1      3
 7     4        0     2  0.1      4
 8     4        1     2  0.1      4
 9     5        0     1  0.05     5

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure the expected output is reproducible data as well. You can do it with `dput(expected_output)` or `datapasta::tribble_format(expected_output)`.
Your expected output is inconsistent (as @Friede mentioned) but it's comprehensible enough.
This solution isn't concise, but it's easier to follow along and make adjustments (imo).

The input (this is a `tidyverse` take):

```
library(tidyverse)

# datapasta::tribble_format()
input <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~age, ~gender, ~response,
  1L,    1,       1,         1,
  2L,    2,       1,         0,
  3L,    2,       1,         1,
  4L,    3,       1,         1,
  5L,    1,       1,         0,
  6L,    1,       1,         0,
  7L,    4,       1,         0,
  8L,    5,       2,         1,
  9L,    6,       2,         1,
  10L,    6,       2,         0,
  11L,    5,       2,         0,
  12L,    4,       1,         1,
  13L,    4,       1,         1,
  14L,    4,       3,         0,
  15L,    2,       3,         0,
  16L,    1,       2,         0,
  17L,    1,       2,         0,
  18L,    2,       2,         1,
  19L,    3,       1,         1,
  20L,    1,       2,         1)
```

Choose the variables you want to process. You don't need to include them all, and not all of them must be present on `input`:

```
variables <- c("age", "gender")
```

The process have one intermediary step to fill values, combinations *etc* and is a good place to your adjustments:

```
aux <- input %>% 
  pivot_longer(any_of(variables), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  count(variable, value, response) %>% 
  mutate(prop = 100 * prop.table(n), .by = c(variable, value)) %>% 
  complete(nesting(variable, value), response, fill = list(n = 0, prop = 0))

> aux
# A tibble: 18 × 5
   variable value response     n  prop
   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1 age          1        0     4  66.7
 2 age          1        1     2  33.3
 3 age          2        0     2  50  
 4 age          2        1     2  50  
 5 age          3        0     0   0  
 6 age          3        1     2 100  
 7 age          4        0     2  50  
 8 age          4        1     2  50  
 9 age          5        0     1  50  
10 age          5        1     1  50  
11 age          6        0     1  50  
12 age          6        1     1  50  
13 gender       1        0     4  40  
14 gender       1        1     6  60  
15 gender       2        0     4  50  
16 gender       2        1     4  50  
17 gender       3        0     2 100  
18 gender       3        1     0   0
```

The `output` will merge the total observations by variable-value with proportions calculated in a wide format:

```
output <- left_join(
  summarise(aux, .by = c(variable, value), n = sum(n)),
  pivot_wider(aux, id_cols = -n, names_from = response, names_glue = "response_{response}", values_from = prop),
  by = c("variable", "value"))

> output
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  variable value     n response_0 response_1
  <chr>    <dbl> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 age          1     6       66.7       33.3
2 age          2     4       50         50  
3 age          3     2        0        100  
4 age          4     4       50         50  
5 age          5     2       50         50  
6 age          6     2       50         50  
7 gender       1    10       40         60  
8 gender       2     8       50         50  
9 gender       3     2      100          0
```

Discard the intermediary helper:

```
rm(aux)
```

Hope it helps.